# OpenCV Bad trained Hog SVM

Tags: opencv, svm, object-detection, svmlight

I found [this](https://github.com/DaHoC/trainHOG/) repository for training a SVM with HOG features. I changed the code so the hog window size is not 64x128 but 64x64 instead as I don't want to detect people. My goal is to detect a car steering wheel. After training I have:

```
True Positives: 303
True Negatives: 461
False Positives: 6
False Negatives: 2
```

My problem is that while testing with my webcam, I got false positives. It detects every circular shape and also some other shapes which doesn't look like a steering wheel at all. The circular shapes are well detected (as I mean that while moving them and rotating them they are still detected) while the other false detected are detected only in a specific position.

Do you have any idea how can I train the SVM correctly?

Comment: Maybe circular shape is the only thing thats in common for most of the steering wheels? How many samples did you use?

Comment: I use 305 positive samples and 379 negative

Comment: You can try to retrain and add the false positives (called "hard samples") to the negative samples! But keep in mind not to use those samples for testing afterwards.

Comment: I mean to add false positives of your webcam testing to the retraining

Comment: I get your idea. Thank you for your help. I write again when I try it :)